# Wide to Long with Two sets of Variables to Reshape

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataset containing 4 dependent variables, 6 independent variables, and 9 covariates. The dataset is arranged in wide format.

I wish to make it in long format, so I can repeat a certain procedure (lm, plot, ...) in a loop, varying the dependent variable and the independent, while keeping the covariates (in lm example).

The data I have looks like:

[image]

And I want it like:

[image]

If I had only one set of variables (dependent only or independent only), I know how to do it, I would use the **reshape** function. But how do I do it when I have two sets of variables ? I need to create 24 different combinations of DV and IV while keeping all covariates in every row.

Would appreciate some guidance. Thank you in advance !

Code for generating random data in the shape of my data:

```
ID = seq(1,5)
DV1 = rnorm(5,0,1)
DV2 = rnorm(5,0,1)
DV3 = rnorm(5,0,1)
DV4 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV1 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV2 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV3 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV4 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV5 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV6 = rnorm(5,0,1)
COV1 = rnorm(5,0,1)
COV2 = rnorm(5,0,1)
COV3 = rnorm(5,0,1)
data = data.frame(ID,DV1,DV2,DV3,DV4,IV1,IV2,IV3,IV4,IV5,IV6,COV1,COV2,COV3)
```

Comment: Can you please show a small reproudcible example

Comment: Subset the data, do the `reshape` twice (or once for each of `DV`, `IV`, `COV`), then `merge` on `ID`. If you want an coded solution, it would help to have sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt` function of `reshape2` package with argument `id` in which you indicate the columns you would like to keep during transformation from wide to narrow format. Please see the code below:

```
set.seed(123)
ID = seq(1,5)
DV1 = rnorm(5,0,1)
DV2 = rnorm(5,0,1)
DV3 = rnorm(5,0,1)
DV4 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV1 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV2 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV3 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV4 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV5 = rnorm(5,0,1)
IV6 = rnorm(5,0,1)
COV1 = rnorm(5,0,1)
COV2 = rnorm(5,0,1)
COV3 = rnorm(5,0,1)
data = data.frame(ID,DV1,DV2,DV3,DV4,IV1,IV2,IV3,IV4,IV5,IV6,COV1,COV2,COV3)

library(reshape2)
data_molten <- melt(data, id = c("ID", "DV1", "DV2", "DV3", "DV4", "COV1", "COV2", "COV3"))
head(data_molten)
```

Output:

```
  ID         DV1        DV2        DV3        DV4        COV1       COV2       COV3 variable      value
1  1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818  1.7869131  0.25331851  1.5164706  0.3796395      IV1 -1.0678237
2  2 -0.23017749  0.4609162  0.3598138  0.4978505 -0.02854676 -1.5487528 -0.5023235      IV1 -0.2179749
3  3  1.55870831 -1.2650612  0.4007715 -1.9666172 -0.04287046  0.5846137 -0.3332074      IV1 -1.0260044
4  4  0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.1106827  0.7013559  1.36860228  0.1238542 -1.0185754      IV1 -0.7288912
5  5  0.12928774 -0.4456620 -0.5558411 -0.4727914 -0.22577099  0.2159416 -1.0717912      IV1 -0.6250393
6  1 -0.56047565  1.7150650  1.2240818  1.7869131  0.25331851  1.5164706  0.3796395      IV2 -1.6866933
```